# filter listview data by selecting ComboBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am learning ASP.Net development & trying to create Web application where ListView data should get filter selection done in ComboBox. I have made ListView & bind it with my database table & tried to put ComboBox filter but getting this error

> (System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context) in output .

VB Code

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Partial Class VB
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim query As String
    Dim strArea As String = Request.QueryString("Country")

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            Me.BindListView()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindListView()
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerId, ContactName, Country FROM Customers"
                cmd.Connection = con
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    lvCustomers.DataSource = dt
                    lvCustomers.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnPagePropertiesChanging(sender As Object, e As PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs)
        TryCast(lvCustomers.FindControl("DataPager1"), DataPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, False)
        Me.BindListView()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub country_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles country.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            If country.SelectedValue <> "All" Then
                query = "Select CutomerId, Contact Name, Country from Customers where Country like '%" + strArea + "%' order by rank;"
            End If
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim table As New DataTable
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Request` read-only property belongs to `Page` class and inherited class members are available only within the members of the class which inherits it(`VB` in your case). Change your code like this:-

```
Partial Class VB
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim query As String
    Dim strArea As String = String.Empty

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            Me.BindListView()
        End If
        strArea  = Request.QueryString("Country")
    End Sub
```

Also, Please note it will be better to check if any value exists within your query string variable before assigning it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but how will it filter the listview data with selcted option in combobox?

Comment: @SuRajPrince - I have answered for your exception message. To answer your filter question, which code you have written? I am not able to figure out and please post where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: I have written code for combobox by referring other tutorial but by selecting any option from combobox listview is not showing filtered data it just work as page refresh. Basically i want is on selection of dropdown from combobox only desire result should come. Please look at my question (code part) last section I have written code to filter.